# Add a disable checkbox to Magento Product Custom Option

Tags: php, custom-options, html

I want to add a `checkbox` to each `product custom option` to `disable/enable` that custom option.
i know that i can remove custom options which i don't need. but some times i need to remove a custom option and add it again in the future and do this several times. i think its sensible to have this kind of disable/enable option for product custom options.

Comment: This does a bit more, but it has an "active" setting for an option: http://www.mageworx.com/advanced-product-options-magento-extension.html

Comment: @Moh3n: Did you find a solution? I am looking for something similar, to set a start date and end date for each custom option